# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to submit an image over ajax but get the error: `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Javascript:

```js
$("form[name='submitProfileImage']").on("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser default submit.

  var formData = new FormData(this);
    
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: "/members/store",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    success: function (msg) {
      alert(msg)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
```

Form:

```js
<form method="POST" name="submitProfileImage">
    <input type="file" hidden id="profileImage" onchange="submit()">
    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-5" href="#" id="selectProfileImage">Add profile image</a>
</form>
```

Route:

```js
Route::post('members/store', 'MembersController@store')->name('members.store');
```

Route table snippet:

```
 POST | members/store | members.store | App\Http\Controllers\MembersController@store
```

Doesn't matter if I remove the method from the form or the type from ajax, still has the same error.Cleared the route table but this made no difference. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show us from where you are getting CSRF token?

Comment: From this in the header: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: can you show us your other routes, there might be a conflict there

Comment: try url: "<?= route('members.store'); ?>"

Answer (score -2):

for image, I think you need to add Content-Type : multipart/form-data to your header.Do that and lets see what difference it would make

Comment: made no difference sadly

Comment: have you tried it on postman or something

Comment: you should also try clear the route cache ```php artisan route:clear```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what do you mean by "for image"?